# Why does list.remove() not remove all items that meet the condition?

Tags: arcpy, list, conditional, remove

I have a bunch of feature classes in a geodatabase, and some of them are empty. I want to generate a list of all feature class names, and then remove the names of any feature classes that are empty. For some reason, the (example) code below removes some, but not *all* of the empty files.

These lines correctly produce a list of all the feature classes:

```
myDir = r'C:\Projects\geodatabase.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = myDir
myfiles = 'MLresult_*' 
file_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(myfiles)
```

If I print the name and the number of records of all files in the list...

```
for file in file_list:
    print(file)
    print(arcpy.management.GetCount(file))
```

The printout is something like:

```
MLresult_2013
9
MLresult_2018
4
MLresult_2020
0
MLresult_2021
0
```

Where multiple files are empty (and the counts are all correct). BUT, when I execute these lines...

```
for file in file_list:
    if arcpy.management.GetCount(file)[0] == "0":
        file_list.remove(file)
```

then the list removes some of the "empty" files, but not all, so the list now looks like:

```
['MLresult_2013', 'MLresult_2018', 'MLresult_2021']
```

Why would it remove `MLresult_2020`, but not `MLresult_2021`, when

```
arcpy.management.GetCount(file)[0] == "0"
```

Is true for both?

Comment: What is `fileB_list`?

Comment: Shouldnt `== "0"` be `== 0`?

Comment: Shapefiles can't be in a geodatabase (different formats). Did you mean "feature classes"?

Comment: @Kadir -- that fileB_list is a typo, I missed it when modifying my actual code for this forum. It is not the reason the code fails.

Comment: @ Vince, yes - thank you. I did mean feature classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it

Answer (score 4):

> Python behind the scenes creates an iterator for your list, and it is
> the iterator which moves through your list one entry at a time. The
> iterator is evaluated once, which means that if you then modify your
> list, the iterator could potentially get ‘lost’ - you also can't use
> the `file` variable to modify your list, since it is just a reference to
> the thing in your list.
> [Reference](https://www.quora.com/Why-can%E2%80%99t-you-modify-lists-through-for-in-loops-in-Python)

You should avoid modifying a list in for loop using its element in the loop, especially avoid removing an item from the list.

You can solve the issue using a list comprehension:

```
file_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(myfiles)

# list comprehension
file_list = [f for f in file_list if arcpy.management.GetCount(f)[0] != 0]
```

But this doesn't remove empty feature classes from the geodatabase. It just removes the items from `file_list` list.